# Using Volley Getting SSLHandshakeException on Android

Tags: android, ssl, apache-commons-httpclient, android-volley, sslhandshakeexception

Our server is using a CA (certificate authority) which is not one of the CA's included on Android (Go Daddy). I am using Volley(https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/) for my network requests, and therefore am unsure of how to deal with this issue. Since the example on the developer site (http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html), explains how to do it  with like HttpUrlConnection.

Answer (score 2):

You have setup your server wrong. You also need to upload intermediate CA to your server. There has to be 2 certificates in your server.

When you execute the below line in you command line interface, you should see 2 certificates in "Certificate Chain" section.

```
openssl s_client -debug -connect api.metrekare.com:443
```